# Como fazer um objecto saltar apenas uma vez. no framework LÖVE?

Tags: lua, löve

Eu estou a tentar fazer um jogo, utilizando a framework `LÖVE` para `Lua`, em que o jogador e uma bola e tem de ultrapassar obstáculos e inimigos mas estou a ter um problema em fazer os saltos.

```lua
function love.keypressed( key )
    if key == "w" then
        print("Teste")
        objects.ball.body:applyForce(0, -300)
    end
end
```

Ao utilizar esta função sempre que pressiono <kbd>w</kbd>, é impresso o "Teste" mas a bola não se mexe, outra alternativa que eu tentei foi o `isDown()` mas se mantivesse primido a bola ia parar as estrelas. Alguma alternativa/solução?

Comment: Seria interessante saber a massa da bola, para vermos se ela resiste ao movimento devido a uma relação massa/força desfavorável. Em tempo: meus conhecimentos em `Lua` são poucos... Não seria o caso de se tentar `objects.ball.body:applyForce(0, 300)` (mudança de sinal)?

Comment: Em primeiro lugar muito obrigado pelas edições na minha pergunta, eu sou novo por aqui.
O problema era mesmo o da massa quando apliquei uma força superior (neste caso -2000), a bola de facto saltou.
O sinal tem de ser negativo pois à medida que a bola sobe o valor do y diminui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para verificar se a bola está em contato com o chão (ou o que quer que seja) você precisa definir as funções de callback para as colisões de objetos

```
g = true
w = love.physics.newWorld(0, 10, true)
w:setCallbacks(beginContact, endContact, nil, nil) --[[Define o nome da funçao a ser 
executa quando contato é estabelecido entre dois objetos e quando o mesmo termina]]

--Definimos agora a funcao
function beginContact (a, b, ev) --Objeto(fixture) a e b e evento de colisão
  g = true
end

function endContact(a, b, ev) 
  g=false
end

--Modificamos o tratamento de teclas
function love.keypressed( key )
    if key == "w" and g then
        print("Teste")
        objects.ball.body:applyForce(0, -300)
    end
end
```

Dessa forma a força só será aplicada quando g=true (bola em contato com o chão), note que não foram verificados os objetos que participaram do evento de colisão, caso existam outros objetos será necessário implementar essa verificação.

Essa implementação pode ser feita usando os métodos setUserData() e getUserData() da tabela devolvida por love.physics.newFixture()

```
bola.fixture:setUserData("Bola")
chao.fixture:setUserData("Chao")
function beginContact (a, b, ev)
   if a:getUserData() == "Bola"and b:getUserData() == "Chao" or 
       a:getUserData() == "Chao" and b:getUserData() == "Bola" then
      g = true
   end
end
```

[Exemplo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-aDh0gDGN0E)

Answer (score 6):

Você deve verificar se a bola está no chão antes de aplicar a força.
Isso impedirá que a bola voe infinitamente, como está acontecendo.

Para isso, você pode verificar se a velocidade em y da bola é zero (ou seja, a bola está no chão), antes de aplicar a força.
Deve ter outras opções melhores (não sei muito de LÖVE), mas deve resolver.
Deve ficar algo do tipo:

```
function love.keypressed( key )
    if key == "w" and objects.ball.y_velocity == 0 then
        print("Teste")
        objects.ball.body:applyForce(0, -300)
    end
end
```

1. https://love2d.org/wiki/Tutorial:Platformer_Jumping

---

Obs: Essa solução só resolve para o objeto andando em plataformas planas (com inclinação zero). Para um plano inclinado e que o objeto deslize a solução anterior causará bugs, pois o objeto estará no chão mas estará se movendo em y. Nesse caso, a solução é verificar colisão com o chão em vez de comparar a velocidade y a zero.